# Mirroring BSTs by insertion

Tags: algorithm, binary-search-tree

> Write a function in C to create a new BST which is the mirror image of a given tree.

I thought of an implementation for this problem which just duplicates the root node from the original tree and then proceeds by discovering new nodes with a DFS traversal and inserting them into the new mirror tree with a different comparison function (i.e. using > instead of < when traversing and inserting nodes).

My question is: will this approach work in every case? I think so but I'd like to know if there are corner cases where my solution will not work (or if there's a better solution).

Comment: Also: something like "switch left and right" in a post-order fashion could definitely work I suppose, but I'm curious if the above could work as well

Comment: A, your solution sounds right. B. You could also "read" the tree into an array, do the swapping there (some math to work out what is swapped with what) and build out the tree again. This is not very memory saving, but should be easy to implement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Recursive solution: mirror left and right children and assign them as right and left children (respectively) of mirrored node. Code below (call mirrorTree(root) to execute):

```
class Node:
  def __init__(self, val, left, right):
    self.val=val
    self.left=left
    self.right=right

def mirrorTree(node):
  new_node=None
  if node:
    new_node=Node(node.val, mirrorTree(node.right), mirrorTree(node.left))
  return new_node
```

Comment: Most of the code is scaffolding... the actual heart of the algorithm can be written as one statement/expression (the line with the  recursive call) !!

Answer (score 0):

Same answer as gen-y-s but just in C.

```
    node *create_empty()
    {
            node *temp = malloc(sizeof(*temp));
            temp->left = left;
            temp->right = right;
            return temp;
    }

    node *add_detail(int value, node *left, node *right)
    {
            temp->value = value;
            temp->left = left;
            temp->right = right;
            return temp;
    }

    node *mirror(node *p)
    {
            if (p) {
                    node = create_empty();
                    node = add_detail(p->value, mirror(p->right), mirror(p->left));
            }
            return node;
    }
```